# perl read multiple file

Tags: perl

in Perl,

How to read multiple file at once,

am genrating report at the end of the month,

per day one log file will create,

i want to read the entire month files ,

my file somthing  like this t.log.mmddyyy

Comment: First: it's "Perl". It's not an acronym. Secondly what did you try, what kind of data to you have? Please read the FAQ regarding how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function will allow you to retrieve a list of files names that match a certain pattern. If you load that list into `@ARGV`, then you can process all the files--even in order with a single loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

sub usage ($) { 
    my $msg = shift;
    die <<"END_MSG";
*** $msg
Usage: $0 --month=nn --year=nn PATH

END_MSG
}

GetOptions( 'month=i' => \my $month, 'year=i'  => \my $year );

usage "Month not specified!" unless $month;
usage "Year not specified!"  unless $year;
usage "Invalid month specified: $month" unless $month > 0 and $month < 13;
usage "Invalid year specified: $year"   unless $year  > 0;

my $directory_path = shift;
die "'$directory_path' does not exist!" unless -d $directory_path;

@ARGV = sort glob( sprintf( "$directory_path/t.log.%02d??%02d", $month, $year ));
while ( <> ) { # process all files 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a

- readdir to get the list of files in the directory
- parse each file name to make sure it matches your format
- open and read each file

Comment: but dircotry contain entire year, but i want to read permonth file, exactly like, end of the month, i will send report, so that, i want to read all log file at once