# How to stream log files content that is constantly changing file names in perl?

Tags: linux, file, perl

I a series of applications on Linux systems that I need to basically constantly 'stream' out or even just 'tail' out but the challenge is the filenames are constantly rolling and changing.

The are all date encoded (dates being in different formats) and each then have different incremented formats.

Most of them start with one and increase, but one doesn't have an extension and then adds an extension past the first file and the other increments a number but once hitting 99 rolls to increment a alpha and returns the numeric to 01 and then up again as it rolls so quickly.

I just have the OS level shell scripting, OS command line utilities, and perl available to me to handle this situation for another application to pickup and read these logs.

The new files are always created right when it starts writing to the new file and groups of different logs (some I am reading some I am not) are being written to the same directory so I cannot just pickup anything hitting the directory.

If I simply 'tail -n 1000000 -f |' them today this works fine for the reader application I am using until the file changes and I cannot setup file lists ranges within the reader application, but can pre-process them so they basically appear as a continuous stream to the reader vs. the reader directly invoking commands to read them.  A [simple Perl log reader like this](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node241.html) also work fine for a static filename but not for dynamic ones. It is critical I don't re-process any logs lines and just capture new lines being written to the logs.

I admit I am not any form a Perl guru, and the best answers / clue I've been able to find so far is the use of [Perl's Glob function to possibly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093477/perl-read-multiple-file) do this but the examples I've found basically reprocess all of the files on each run then seem to stop.

Example File Names I am dealing with across multiple apps I am trying to handle..

- **appA**_YYMMDD.log
- **appA**_YYMMDD_0001.log
- **appA**_YYMMDD_0002.log
- WS01**APPB**_YYMMDD.log
- WS02**APPB**_YYMMDD.log
- WS03**AppB**_YYMMDD.log
- **APPC**MMDD_A01.log
- **APPC**MMDD_B01.log
- YYYYMMDD_001_**APPD**.log

As denoted above the files do not have the same inode and simply monitoring the directory for change is not possible as a lot of things are written there. On the dev system it has more than 50 logs being written to the directory and thousands of files and I am only trying to retrieve 5.  I am seeing if multitail can be made available to try that suggestion but it is not currently available and installing any additional RPMs in the environment is generally a multi-month battle.

*ls -i
24792 APPA_180901.log
24805 APPA__180902.log
17011 APPA__180903.log
17072 APPA__180904.log
24644 APPA__180905.log
17081 APPA__180906.log
17115 APPA__180907.log*

So really the root of what I am trying to do is simply a continuous stream regardless if the file name changes and not have to run the extract command repeatedly nor have big breaks in the data feed while some script figures out that the file being logged to has changed. I don't need to parse the contents (my other app does that)..  Is there an easy way of handling this changing file name?

Comment: Why and how does the filename change -- does the inode stay the same?

Comment: Do you need to keep track of individual files or just get all logs?

Comment: The app (which i have zero control) is written to just dump them out fire and forget. Each file is independent vs an extension of the original file with no begin or end marker within the file itself..

Comment: My impression was that files are being appended to and you want to keep fetching the new content ... is that not correct? Or do you mean that it's always new files which you need to read, but that they have hard-to-predict names?

Comment: I want to keep fetching new content from them as if they were a syslog feed basically, but being the tail read stops at the end of each file and moves onto the next one (which ive figured out the convention for each) im looking for a way to basically script the line by line copy for a continuous read based on changing file names and only reading the latest at any given time.

Comment: Have you tried 'multitail':                                                                        https://superuser.com/questions/1243634/how-to-tail-multiple-pipe-files-or-streams

Answer (score 1):

How about monitoring the log directory for changes with Linux inotify, e.g. `Linux::inotify2`? Then you could detect when new log files are created, stop reading from the old log file and start reading from the new log file.

Comment: This is what I had in mind but it is unclear (to me) whether they need to keep track of individual files, in which case the first question (for me) is whether the inode changes or not.

Comment: That's why I suggested to monitor the directory, not the files. Any file name change should trigger the watcher.

Comment: Yes, that will trigger it for a new file. But how does one find out which old file that new file adds to? If that is what is happening (and if that is needed to be known).  I couldn't figure out what exactly is going on in the question, what I think affects how/what to monitor.

Comment: I am not sure this will work but I am at least looking at it. Put some additional info in the question. Can inotify instead of just a path handle regex patterns for files under a directory?

Comment: I would implement the file name detection, i.e. your regex -> log file type, into the inotify directory watcher. You'll need a hash that holds the currently monitored log file for each monitored type. If the code recognizes that a new file has been added for a log file type then it means the log file has changed, i.e. the watcher should trigger (whatever system you use) to stop reading from the old one and start reading from the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Try [tailswitch](https://metacpan.org/pod/tailswitch). I created this script to tail log files that are rotated daily and have YYYY-MM-DD on their names. To use this script, you just say:

```
% tailswitch '*.log'
```

The quoting prevents the shell from interpreting the glob pattern. The script will perform glob pattern from time to time to switch to a newer file based on its name.